# Why is only one thread used in VS2013 if no testsettings file is set?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

Given is the following unit test class which contains 3 tests. Each tests just writes its thread id to the stdout.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("thread id: {0}",System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("thread id: {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("thread id: {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

If no tessettings file is set on solution level, the thread id will be the same for all tests. 
[image]

As soon as the testsettings file is set to the solution, the thread id will be different for each thread(Since thread will then be loaded by thread pool).

This is my(default) testsettings file used for this demo

```
<TestSettings
  id="bc3c3610-4c7e-4f77-ad67-748d0f8d07d9"
  name="TestSettings1"
  enableDefaultDataCollectors="false"
  xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description><!--_locID_text="Description1"-->These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Deployment enabled="false" />
</TestSettings>
```

Question:

- Why is only one thread used for executing unittests if the
  testsettings file is not set explicitly to the solution?